# How to compute the maximum of $f(x)=\prod_{i=0}^3(x-x_i)$ $x_i = x_0 + ih$, for $i = 1, 2, 3$, and $h>0$

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods

I want to ask a question looks like a little bit trivial:

> Given that $x_i = x_0 + ih$, $for$  $i = 1, 2, 3$, and $h>0$, at which point the function $f(x)=\prod_{i=0}^3(x-x_i)$ where $x\in[x_0,x_3]  $will attain its maximum?

I know compute its derivatives and check the global minimum/maximum points is a way. I computed the maximum of $g(x)=\prod_{i=0}^2(x-x_i)$ and the process is a little bit complicated. I wonder know is there any other way to compute? I noticed that the space of any adjacent points is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Rolle's theorem we can see that $f'$ has a zero in each interval $I_1 = (x_0, x_1)$, $I_2 = (x_1, x_2)$, and $I_3 = (x_2, x_3)$, and there can be no more zeros of $f'$ since $\operatorname{deg} f' = 3$.

$f$ is negative in $I_1$ and $I_3$ and positive in $I_2$, therefore the maximum must occur at the zero of $f'$ in $I_2$.

Finally, $f$ is *symmetric* with respect to $x_s = \frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$:
$$
 f(x_s -h) = f(x_s + h) \implies f'(x_s) = 0
$$
so that the maximum of $f$ on $[x_0, x_3]$ is attained at $\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$.

More generally, you can use the symmetry of $f$ to express it as
$$
 f(x) = (x-x_s - \frac{3h}{2})(x-x_s - \frac{h}{2})(x-x_s + \frac{h}{2})(x-x_s + \frac{3h}{2}) \\
= \left( (x-x_s)^2 - \frac{9h^2}{4}\right)\left( (x-x_s)^2 - \frac{h^2}{4}\right) \\
= g\left( (x-x_s)^2 \right)
$$
where $g$ is defined as
$$
 g(t) = \left( t - \frac{h^2}{4}\right)\left( t - \frac{9h^2}{4}\right) \, .
$$
$g$ is a parabola and its derivative is zero at the vertex
$$ t = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{h^2}{4} + \frac{9h^2}{4} \right)  = \frac{5h^2}{4}
$$ 
It follows that 
$$
 f'(x) =  2(x-x_s) g'\left( (x-x_s)^2 \right) 
$$
is zero if $x=x_s$ or if $(x-x_s)^2 = \frac{5h^2}{4}$, i.e. at the points
$$
x_s \, , \,  x_s - \frac{\sqrt 5 h}{2} \, , \, x_s + \frac{\sqrt 5 h}{2}
$$
so that are the points where $f$ attains the maximum and the two minima in $[x_0, x_3]$.

Comment: how to get $f'(x_s)=0$?

Comment: @YangGao: Differentiating  $f(x_s -h) = f(x_s + h)$ with respect to $h$ gives $-f'(x_s) = f'(x_s)$.

Comment: Thank you.Can I ask you another question? If I want to got the minimum point, is there any other except check its derivative ?

Comment: @YangGao: See update.

Comment: Excellent...Thank you!!  Do you think the question I ask too simple for you?